# How to change default request completion queue?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, afnetworking, alamofire

I am doing an app which has numerous APIs, each API's response has to be imported into the core data. I am aware **Alamofire** completion handler will be in the main thread by default. I would like to change this into background thread as i would do core data import operation in the request completion. Can you please guide me how can I set my background thread as default thread in the request completion?

I hate to set this in each API request, Instead i would like to set this in single place as I always do in AFNetworking which had property called **completionQueue** in the **AFHTTPSessionManager**  so I created subclass for AFHTTPSessionManager then I easily changed the default thread. I don't find similar thing in **Alamofire**. Please guide me with better solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almofire does not provide a method to change the completion queue. But You can extend the `Request` class and add a custom response method:

```
   extension Request {

     public func responseOnCustomQueue(completionHandler: (NSURLRequest?, NSHTTPURLResponse?, NSData?, NSError?) -> Void) -> Self {
       let queue = dispatch_get_main_queue() // custom queue for all requests
       return self.response(queue: queue, completionHandler: completionHandler)
     }
   }
```

This way you do not have to specify the custom queue each time.